# What is exactly a bundler?

Tags: bundler, dependency-management, package-managers

I am pretty confused about what a bundler really is and mostly its difference, if there is, between a package manager? Is bun for instance a bundler?

I haven't found yet a clear explanation resolving my hesitations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bundler bundles many files in one file; package manager manages external (third-party) packages of code; Bun is a bundler and a package manager (and other things) – all in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Package Manager**: Manages and installs software packages and libraries.

**Bundler**: Optimizes and bundles assets like JavaScript and CSS files in web development ("doing minify & uglify and all of those things").

for exmaple :

**npm** is a package manager while **webpack** is the bundler that is the most famous used with npm.

concerning bun its all in one its mainly a package manager but it has it`s own bundler inside.

more info in it`s docs here [Bun docs](https://bun.sh/)